# Careers 2.0 - Open source section - can't add technolgies

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, open-source

Keep on getting this 'Use Original' link, and it doesn't seem to like what I enter into technogloies.  After that, I can't save (well, the save button is there but does nothing), and I loose my changes.

[image: UseOriginal]

Mac 10.7.5, Chrome 26.0.1410.65

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the "Use Original" link is to restore the values from the original import (e.g. from GitHub, CodePlex, Bitbucket...) in case they have been overridden by the user.

So in your example, the project has originally been imported with **Technologies** = `javascript`. You're free to override this on your Careers profile with any set of technologies you want, the "Use Original" link is simply for your convenience.

Try: refresh page, edit technologies, ignore "Use Original" link, save. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: Thanks Max, unf no.  What I had to do was cut and paste the technologies to a temporary place, fill in all of the other info, and add technologies *last*.  If I didn't do that, the Use Original link would show up and 'Save' would not save any of the other non-technology changes.